# Including other libraries in Zend Framework applications

Tags: git, zend-framework

I have a ZF application using the standard structure:

```
application/
    <etc>
library/
    Zend/
public/
tests/
```

I also have a separate library using the following structure:

```
library/
    <classes>
tests/
   library/
```

Both use git for source control. I'd like to include the library in the application, but I'm struggling to find a nice, maintainable way to do this. The contents of the library's 'library' folder are structured so as to be suitable for autoloading, so ideally I want the contents of library/ to exist in the ZF app's library directory:

```
library/
    Zend/
    <classes>
```

I can't use git submodules alone, as I can't include a sub-folder of a repo as a submodule, and submodules have to exist in a sub-folder themselves (so I'd end up with library/something/<classes>).

I've been playing with [these subtree extensions](http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) to git, which are pretty cool, and solve the first problem (by allowing me to split out the library folder of my library project into it's own repo). But I still have the problem of not being to include the contents of this repo into my library folder directly.

I'm trying to avoid adding a whole new folder with autoloading just for this lib.

Does anyone know of a nice solution to this, or does anyone use a slightly different project structure to avoid this?

Comment: Well i cant comment on the Git issues since i use SVN, but as far as outright placement i would put the other lib in `library/PackageName` and load them from there.

Comment: Problem with that is the classes in the library are already namespaced in PackageName, so the only way for me to do this would be to create a split repo of my library as library/PackageName/* and submodule include that, which seems messy.

Comment: Im not ure how you mean by the namespacing conflict - you can register your own autoloader namespace and point it to wherever you want so having something like `PackageName/PackageName` shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: Yeah I guess semantically I'm averse to autoloading a subfolder of library, which already has an autoloader pointed at it. I think you're right this is probably my best bet though - feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting the separate library alongside Zend in /library and adding:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "YourLibName"
```

To application.ini ? Thats what I would do.

If its not already done also add this to bootstrap:

```
 protected function _initAppAutoload()
{
    $moduleLoad = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
       'namespace' => '',
       'basePath'   => APPLICATION_PATH
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's getting the files into /library that's the issue, as I'm wanting to use git submodules or some other method to allow me to easily keep it up to date.